# Why would a series of cells not be suitable for a car battery?

Tags: electric-circuits, batteries

A car battery needs to supply a current of $200A$ to turn over the starter motor. Explain why a battery made of a series of cells would not be suitable for a car battery.

My thinking:

I'm thinking it could be something to do with the internal resistances of the cells. Would that and the high current somehow result in a short circuit of the individual cells?

Comment: think for a second, how could  cells connected in series increase the short-circuited current beyond the ratio of the open circuited voltage and internal resistance of any one of them? and when answered what could be a more scientific explanation?

Comment: A car batter _is_ a series of cells. It's usually six 2V lead-acid cells for a battery voltage of 12V... who made this ridiculous question?

Comment: As CuriousOne mentioned, your intuition is right: a car battery made of a series of cells is suitable for the application. In fact, that is what a car battery is (note: the name "battery" is derived from the phrase "battery of cells" where "battery" has the same meaning as "battery of cannons": it means series/row/group).

Comment: The question is from the textbook "Cambridge International AS and A level Physics 2nd edition".

Comment: Give the book a new function as a doorstop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the question in context.

[image]

> **I'm thinking it could be something to do with the internal resistances of the cells.**

Given the context, it seems reasonable to deduce that the person who wrote the question wanted you to consider the internal resistance.

---

In real life, car batteries *are* made up of a series of cells. This fact makes this question seem somewhat unrealistic and perhaps misleading or confusing. It could certainly be argued that the question was poorly chosen. However if I encountered such a question in an exam, I would try to make the best of it by proceeding along the path the question composer obviously had in mind.

Having done so there are numerous ways you could explore the subject for a fuller and more accurate understanding of the scenario.

Note that a typical 12V car-battery has six lead-acid cells. You could find out the typical internal resistance of each cell and calculate their effect on the battery as a whole.

From earlier chapters in the book, you can work out the power, in Watts, of the starter motor. You could then calculate the power dissipated in the battery's internal resistance for a one-cell, six-cell and twenty-cell battery (at 2V per cell and using whatever "typical" value you find out for internal resistance per cell)

You could also find out if the internal resistance depends on temperature or current or other factors.

Comment: Thank you for that context!  I could not figure out what the OP was thinking without it.  The textbook would have been much clearer saying "... a battery made of a series of *these* cells ..." so that we know to use the pre-defined values from earlier in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the detail! Unfortunately, that still doesn't qualify as a well written text/exercise book.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I agree. In these situations, at this level of education, it may be best to temporarily put aside criticism of the question and work out what the person writing the question wanted you to do. It may be possible, assuming time permits, to later add some notes about what you actually know about car batteries and/or open up a discussion with a teacher.

Comment: A prime example of why you need to be reasonably familiar with a technological system before trying to build an example problem around it. Here the author of the question is trying to make a perfectly valid point, but only ends up confusing an alert reader because the the author doesn't really understand what a car battery *is*.  Makers of real car batteries evade the problem by designing the individual cells to have very low internal resistance so that even six in series offer much less resistance than the starter coil.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Certainly the motivated student can (and should) make this a learning moment by wondering what the author was up to, but it remains a failure on the author's part and the question stinks.

Comment: One of the most important things a student has to learn is that not every sequence of words makes a meaningful sentence and that authority doesn't come automatically with textbooks. This may be painful, at times, but it's better they learn to trust their own intuition and question what they see.

Comment: @dmckee: OK, my job here is to work out how to improve this answer based on your comment. The only way I can think of at the moment is to paraphrase your comment in the answer. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: while my answer is indeed correct, RedGrittyBrick's answer properly addresses the context of the OP's question*

Nobody can explain why a battery made of a series of cells would not be suitable for a car battery, **because such series of cells ARE INDEED suitable for car batteries.**

In fact, every car battery in the field today is a collection of 6 lead-acid cells in series, each one providing 2V for a sum total of 12V.

[image]